# Workflow for Git

Tags: git, tfs

We are currently migrating from TFVC to Git source control (in TFS) so there have been some growing pains.  For one I am used to having the concept of a shelveset.  The shelveset allows me to make a quick backup on the TFS server without worrying about that history/description showing in the repository when checked-in/merged to a given branch.  Therefore, I use the shelveset as a backup mechanism to ensure a copy of my current working code is stored on the server each day before I leave (our hardware here has been less than rock solid).

I am now looking to reproduce this style of workflow using Git.  I have been advised to use a personal "feature" branch commit/push my work in progress (WIP) changes, then prior to pull request interactive rebase the commit history squashing the commits.  Is this the best way to go about this?  The problem I have is I ran into another indirectly related error where merging in master changes mid WIP resulted in a bunch of rename/delete conflicts.

For what it is worth, I was told about stash but everywhere I look indicates stash is only local so I would have no remote backup.  If there is quite simply a better workflow than my comments describe I am all ears.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, I learned `git` years ago and by myself so, I understand the pain...when I find someone in that situation I always recommend this article: https://themeteorchef.com/blog/defining-a-simple-git-workflow/#!

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to push a git stash to a remote repository?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1550378/2747593)

Comment: Do you mean you have migrated from TFVC to Git in TFS?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT correct I have edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Hackerman good article thanks.  Unfortunately it doesn't address my concerns of backing up WIP on remote.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that when you don’t want to do a commit of half-done work just so you can get back to this point later, then you can use `git stash` command. But you won't have a remote backup.

Since you want to have a remote backup, making new branch will be a good option. Branches in Git are very lightweight, so creating, pushing and removing from server is very simple and fast. If you want others to review your code, you can create a [Pull Request](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/pull-requests), after merging the code into the master branch, delete this branch.

Comment: Won't this still require re-basing/squashing to get the history down to one description versus all the work in progress descriptions until the feature or bug fix is complete on a final commit?  If I am understanding you the recommendation is to follow my approach of treating a branch like a shelveset you can keep adding too, but the problem is the rebase/squash step.  Maybe there just isn't a way around this with git.